# Move an object in the direction its pointing Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm messing about in actionscript 3 and am trying to move an object, I can get it to move but only on the y axis
I have it set up so the object and rotate
What I am trying to do is move it in the direction it is pointing so it is not just restricted to move only along the y or x axis

anyone have any tips?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Get its `rotation`, convert to radians, move as Descartes says. Should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some basic trigonometry should do the trick.

```
var speed:Number = 10;
var angle:Number = Math.PI/2;

obj.x += speed * Math.cos(angle);
obj.y += speed * Math.sin(angle);
```

For more advanced wizardry I would recommend learning linear algebra. A good start can be made **[here](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/)** :)